# Fabricjs using variable to set top/left

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to use a variable to set top and left on create an object in Fabric.js:

```
var rt = data[0];
var rl = data[1];
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    top : rt,
    left : rl,
    width : 60,
    height : 80,
    fill : 'red'
});
canvas.add(rect);
// or
rect.set({
    top: rt,
    left: rl,
});
canvas.renderAll();
```

But this does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Please try using `rect.setCoords()`